# What is "completed framework" in Mesos Dashboard?

Tags: mesos

Mesos marks frameworks complete and the frameworks wouldn't accept any more tasks. Is this due to scheduler getting disconnected from the mesos master ? How can we avoid this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A framework is marked completed when the master thinks it has terminated and will not try to reconnect. This occurs when the framework is torn down (see the [teardown endpoint](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/master/teardown/)) or becomes disconnected and does not re-register within the `failover_timeout`.

The default `failover_timeout` is zero seconds, so that might be what is happening here: production frameworks should usually set a non-default `failover_timeout` in their `FrameworkInfo` when they register with the Mesos master (recommended values are quite large, such as one week). For more suggestions on writing production-quality Mesos frameworks, see the [Mesos docs](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/high-availability-framework-guide/).